# Firebase cloud messaging notification not received by device

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having an issue with FireBase Cloud Messaging in which I get the Token from the device and send the notification test through the Google Firebase notification console however, the notification is never logged nor pushed to the android virtual device.  The documentation for FCM is almost exactly the code that I have below and little else in the way of what else you would have to do to get push notifications working with firebase.  I have gone through all of the setup information (build.gradle additions, Installing google play services, etc...) as specified in the documentation but still do not have messages generating.  I do receive a one-time error immediately after pushing the notification that states "I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used" but that is the only data that is output and I did not find anything related to Tag Manager requirements and FCM on the googles.  What is wrong with the code that I am not receiving my push notifications to the logcat or the device? Please let me know any further information that would be helpful.
Thanks.

**NotificationGenie.java**

```
public class NotificationGenie extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "Firebase_MSG";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PostLoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tf2spyprofile)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.test.movile_android">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DashBoardActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".NewOrderActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".PostLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>

<service
    android:name=".NotificationGenie">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: google play services is not installed on virtual device.  check this link if you want to see how to send notification from server http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/06/firebase-cloud-messaging-push.html

Comment: You can visit this thread. It has clear description on firebase cloud messaging
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046270/google-fcm-getintent-dont-returning-expected-data-when-app-is-in-background-stat

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have placed your service outside the application tag. Change bottom to this.

```
<service
    android:name=".NotificationGenie">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

</application>
```

Comment: I don't know why <intent-filter> details is not listed in many of tutorials

Comment: it might be because it is not needed now

Comment: @tristan 
I don't why i have same issue, and my service is still with in application like what you mentioned.

I think my device id is storing in the firebase server

Answer (score 86):

*"You must also keep in mind that to receive Messages sent from Firebase Console, App must be in background, not started neither hidden."* --- According to @Laurent Russier's comment.

I never got any message from Firebase, until i put my app in the background.

This is true only on usb connection for emulator you get notification in foreground as well

Comment: I have to open the app and next press the home button?

Comment: No, you need to make sure your app is on background to get a Notification message from console

Comment: You can test using http://pushtry.com easier than Firebase console. You can also send custom JSON.

Comment: Thanks @HtmlTosin! It worked for me too on the App that I am migrating from GCM to FCM. However, when I tested on the following example project I could send Push Notifications through Firebase Console even when the App is in foreground: https://github.com/ton1n8o/FCMTutorial Weird...

Comment: I am not getting in the foreground, even after installing application build on phone

Comment: It also takes time depending on internet connectivity. Took about 2 min in my case

Answer (score 47):

I had the same problem and it is solved by defining enabled, exported to true in my service

```
  <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Actually, I was finding that I was only receiving notifications when my app was running. If I restarted the phone, notifications wouldn't come through. But after setting the `enabled` and `exported` attributes, the push notifications come through fine now. Thanks, Hoby! :-)

Comment: I think it would probably be a good idea to add the same two attributes to your `MyInstanceIDListenerService` service, too.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying a lot of things, but it is the solution. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: Not necessary. Tried Firebase Sample Messaging Project - with and without "enabled" and "exported" - it's excessive. Helped running and hiding app to see notification at topbar - see Html Tosin's answer.

Comment: As per android docs enabled is `true` by default and exported means if service can be invoked by components external to the app. Not sure why this is necessary here.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#exported

Comment: Worked for me too! Tutorial I watched had "exported=false", it worked when I changed to true :)

Answer (score 14):

Call `super.OnMessageReceived()` in the Overriden method. This worked for me!
Finally!

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue of Firebase cloud messaging not received by device.

In my case package name defined on Firebase Console Project was diferent than that the one defined on Manifest & Gradle of my Android Project.

As a result I received token correctly but no messages at all.

To sumarize, it's mandatory that Firebase Console package name and Manifest & Gradle matchs.

You must also keep in mind that to receive Messages sent from Firebase Console, App must be in background, not started neither hidden.

Comment: "You must also keep in mind that to receive Messages sent from Firebase Console, App must be in background, not started neither hidden."

Comment: What do you mean when you say "not started neither hidden"?

Comment: That's a typo. That app has to be running but in the background. If you have the app currently open when the push notification comes in the OS will not display it.

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem but I had still had some debris in my manifest from the old GCM. When I took the following permission out of my manifest it fixed the error.
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I noticed mergedmanifest was missing the receiver. So I had to include:

```
 <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: even i am using latest firebase 18.0.0 still i was not getting notification. But your solution worked for me.

Comment: I thought FirebaseInstanceIdService was depreciated. What is this receiver

Comment: I spent the whole day investigating and try all approaches, suggestions from Firebase official page, SO.... and this is the one which just make FCM work for my app.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, but in my case I was missing the [`google-services` plugin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#3) from my Gradle build (I was adding Firebase to an existing project).

I added the following to my root `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

and the following to the end of my `app`-level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I then had to download the `google-services.json` file from the Firebase Console (having originally imported an existing Google Cloud project) and copy it to my `app` directory`.

Comment: I rembember reading this in the firebase config steps but never understood where exacly those lines go. :(

Answer (score 6):

If you have just added FCM to an existing app, `onTokenRefresh()` will NOT be called. I got it to run by uninstalling the app and installing it again.

Answer (score 6):

After spending hours on this issue I finally realised the problem when I intentionally corrupted the format of the "google-services.json" and my build still succeeded. My IDE(AndroidStudio) does not notice the changes in this file. I tried many things, "reload from disk", gradle task "cleanBuildCache", new virtual device, uninstalling/reinstalling the app etc but none worked.

For me the solution was in `AndroidStudio -> Build -> Clean Project` and `Build -> Rebuild Project`

PS: Also make sure "google-services.json" is in the "app" folder.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. The package name of my app in FCM's console was different from the package name in my local. Even though I had fixed that in the google-services.json, I still had to uninstall the app, clean build, rebuild, redeploy. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I just turned on WiFi and mobile data in the emulator and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Also it is perfect in my case but question is that why does this happen? Why do we need to turn off/on mobile data?

Comment: I think it's all about simulating the environment on the emulator. that's it.

Comment: Not only on emulator, It sometime happens in real device too.

Comment: OMG, can't beleive this is what worked after trying out so many fixes. I had my mobile data ON in the emulator and when I turned the WiFi ON, it workd. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you copying your device token, it might copying the space, double check you have copied the correct token

Answer (score 1):

You need to  Follow Below Manifest Code (must have Service in manifest)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="soapusingretrofitvolley.firebase">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <service
                android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>

            <service
                android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Error: uresolved class 'MyFirebaseInstanceIDService'

Comment: why did you add two firebase services?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, I checked my code. I tried to fix everything that was mentioned here. lastly the problem was so stupid. My device's `Sync` was off. that was the only reason I wasn't receiving notifications as expected.

[image]

Comment: It is strange. I also disable Sync, even don't authorize in Google. Before everything worked, I hardly changed anything, but now it doesn't connect. Will search further.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    int requestCode = 0;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX);
    NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText("hello").setLargeIcon(((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dog)).getBitmap())
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dog)).getBitmap()))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build());
```

Comment: when i am clear my recent not come notification please help me how can i fix this issue and when i am disconnect to usb debuging mode then my phone notification context doesnt show

Answer (score 0):

```
    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Firebase Notifications -->
    <service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Error: uresolved class 'MyFirebaseInstanceIDService'

Comment: You need to create a Class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService for Firebase Service

Answer (score 0):

I've been working through this entire post and others as well as tutorial videos without being able to solve my problem of not receiving messages, the registration token however worked.

Until then I had only been testing the app on the emulator. After trying it on a physical phone it instantly worked without any prior changes to the project.

Answer (score 0):

As if you want your app to run in > 24 versions too, follow these:

1.Add this in your strings.xml

> < string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">
>   fcm_default_channel

2. Add this meta-data in your manifest file:

> < meta-data
>               android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
>               android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

3.for creating notifications (with images) use this method where you are handling notifications, if directly then add in the firebasemessaging service or if you are using some util class then add in that util class :

```
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public static void createBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, int icon, String message, Uri alarmSound) {
        final int NOTIFY_ID = 0; // ID of notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String id = mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id); // default_channel_id
        String title = mContext.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent intent;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        if (notificationManager == null) {
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, title, importance);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, id);
            intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
            bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
            bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
            bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);

            builder.setContentTitle(title)        // required
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)   // required
                    .setContentText(message) // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                    .setTicker(title)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        } else {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, id);
            intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
            bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
            bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
            bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);

            builder.setContentTitle(title)     // required
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)   // required
                    .setContentText(message) // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                    .setTicker(title)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }
```

Follow these steps and your notification will come in the notification tray.

Comment: Where do you put the createBigNotification method from and where do you call it from?

Comment: @Ssenyonjo you can add it in your broadcast receiver or the Activity/Fragment file which you will access globally in the app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I manually killed some google play services and forgot about it.

Later, I have to restart the device, after that I can receive notification without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

2 mistakes that I had to correct, after which the issue was resolved.

Referring to the official documentation gave this nice snippet which helped confirm the Subscription status.

```
 Firebase.messaging.subscribeToTopic(TOPIC)
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        var topicSubscriptionStatus = "Subscribed"
                        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                            topicSubscriptionStatus = "Subscribe failed"
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, topicSubscriptionStatus)
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, topicSubscriptionStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
```

1. my topic name had a typo "/topic/" instead of the correct one "/topics/". Right after correcting this the service started receiving the messages
2. I had to add the flag "FLAG_IMMUTABLE" on the PendingIntent (error in logcat mentioned this is needed from S)

(I m on Tiramisu)

Answer (score 0):

Add in your app manifest
Check docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

```
<service
android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
android:exported="false">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
 </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on kotlin backend service.

I successfully received messageId from FCM like projects/project_name/messages/0:1111111111011111%bd00d111bd00d111, but don't see push on android device.

My problem was in forming message to FCM.
Incorrect:

```
    private fun formFcmMessage(data: Dto): MulticastMessage =
        repository.findById(data.textId).get().let {
            MulticastMessage.builder()
                .addAllTokens(data.getFcmTokens())
                .putData("title", it.header)
                .putData("body", it.body)
                .build()
        }
```

Correct:

```
    private fun formFcmMulticastMessage(data: Dto): MulticastMessage =
        repository.findById(data.textId).get().let {
            MulticastMessage.builder()
                .addAllTokens(data.getFcmTokens())
                .setNotification(
                    Notification.builder()
                        .setTitle(it.header)
                        .setBody(it.body)
                        .build()
                )
                .build()
        }
```

As you see, add notification info like title and body by method putData() is incorrect. This info should be added by setNotification() method.

Thanks for it man from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbAoRzU7OXY&t=307s)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I allowed the Notification From App Setting and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the application was not having a **permission for** **NOTIFICATION** so i allowed it manually you can add program for doing same.

Also I haven't added one more **PERMISSION**  which was:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>`

So these two things worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I followed all the steps according to the firebase website to set up sending notifications for Android APPs. I tried many times but I can't received the notifications no matter on virtue device or physical device. After I changed some settings(those settings about receiving notifications in the SETTING section ) in virtue device and physical device, both virtual and physical devices started receiving notifications.

Answer (score -2):

maybe it is from the connection 
I changed the connection from Ethernet to wireless the it worked without doing anything else