# Firebase onTokenRefresh() is not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

In my `MainActivity`in my log, I can see the token using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` and it display the generated token.  But it seems like in my  `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` where it is extends to `FirebaseInstanceIdService`, the `onTokenRefresh()` is not called, where in this function it was said that the token is initially generated here. I needed to call `sendRegistrationToServer()` that's why I'm trying to know why it doesn't go in the `onTokenRefresh()`.

Here is my code

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService  extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {


@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase FCM force onTokenRefresh() to be called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454501/firebase-fcm-force-ontokenrefresh-to-be-called)

Comment: Please read the questions completely. This question is not duplicate of the question you mentioned. @Machado

Answer (score 106, accepted):

> onTokenRefresh in FirebaseInstanceIdService is only called when a new token is generated. If your app was previously installed and generated a token then onTokenRefresh would not be called. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app to force the generation of a new token, this would cause onTokenRefresh to be called.

Also be sure that your FirebaseInstanceIdService is properly defined in your AndroidManifest.xml

In your Manifest File.

```
 <service
        android:name="com.bnt.etailers.fcm.MyFireBaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.bnt.etailers.fcm.GCMNotificationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

FirebaseInstanceIdService class

```
public class MyFireBaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {


private static final String TAG = MyFireBaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    if (refreshedToken!=null) {
        SettingPreferences.setStringValueInPref(this, SettingPreferences.REG_ID, refreshedToken);
    }
    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
// [END refresh_token]

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}}
```

FirebaseMessagingService class.

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated


public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super();
}


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {

}}
```

Comment: The documentation seems confusing(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client), it says The registration token may change when:The app deletes Instance ID, and if I manually call                             FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId(); I was expecting a new token generated, but nothing actually happens in this case, onTokenRefresh is never called.

Comment: Why save the token to shared preferences - if you can call [FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) at any time to get its value?

Comment: @WenChao make sure you call InstanceID of the playservice by `InstanceID.getInstance(this).deleteInstanceID()` and call it from background thread, after u successfully delete it, call `InstanceID.getInstance(this).getID()` to generate new token

Comment: @Alexander Farber, it's because you can only get the token once, you need to persist it to use it later. For example, I'm doing an app that does not need the user to be registered, but it he wants to subscribe to certain update, he can register, I can send the token of his device with his data, but if I would got the token when he first installed the app, that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: I am testing it on `kitkat and above` devices on `kitkat`  `onTokenRefresh` method is not triggering `FCM version 11.6.2`

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem like you. My mistake was the following: I placed my `<service>` tags outside the `<application>` tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Now mine looks like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

And it works without any problem.

Comment: Credits goes to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351354/firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-not-received-by-device

Comment: great answer...is this the facebook id that gets returned?.......cause I'm trying to do that and I'm getting a very large token

Comment: Facebook? Firebase? You get the token for Firebase Cloud Messaging in your FirebaseInstanceIDService subclass's onTokenRefresh method and yes, it is a long string, my token is 152 character long.

Comment: this is the solution for me.

Comment: @viplezer on my `KITKAT` not able to get `token` above its working. please help

Answer (score 17):

Yes this might happen some times.

Please call the following method wherever you want to get your fcm id.

```
    try {
            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.d("Firbase id login", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Good one. After few reinstalls, token stop to refresh, but direct getToken did  return correct token.

Answer (score 14):

Try re-install the app, by uninstall it first from your device or emulator. It will then generate a new token, thus onTokenRefresh() will be called again.

Answer (score 13):

In my case I forgot to add internet permission in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope most people won't make this mistake.

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

in `onCreate` method to delete token.

Comment: `Thread t = new Thread()` will solve the `MAIN_THREAD Exception`

Answer (score 4):

Reinstalling did the trick for me!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have added

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

this to bottom of the app.gradle file

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I tried everything but `onTokenRefresh` was never called. Then I change my **WiFi** and I connect to different **network**, Now it worked!!. Previous WiFi has good internet connectivity, Don't know why it was happening. May be this can help someone.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced that MyFirebaseInstanceIDService is not called when you are running your application on a device where internet connectivity is not available. In this way onTokenRefresh() is not called. So make sure that your device must has internet connection during running your application for taking updated FirebaseToken.

Also uninstall the previous app & **Re-Install** it for taking updated token.
The registration token change when:

1) The app deletes Instance ID

2) The app is restored on a new device

3) The user uninstalls/reinstall the app

4) The user clears app data.

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with that for over an hour, then I changed the following code and it suddenly worked.

handle your refreshedToken as such:

```
String refreshedToken;
    try {
        refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        Localytics.setPushRegistrationId(refreshedToken);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token, catch: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Try adding 
android:exported="true"> to both MyFirebaseMessagingService and MyFirebaseInstanceIDService in manifest so it looks like that:

```
<service
        android:name="com.localytics.android.sample.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.localytics.android.sample.fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Uninstall your app, Install again, worked. Tested on real device.

android:exported="true" is a default option so you can also remove that entirely and it will be set to true.

Also if you want to call onTokenRefresh more explicitly, you can simply call that anywhere in your code:

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Localytics.setPushRegistrationId(refreshedToken);
```

You don't have to rely on broadcast being received any more

Comment: You say "android:exported=true" but the code sample says "android:exported=false".  Which is it?

Comment: sorry man, updated and expanded, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons to not calling the onTokenRefresh methon not called. I have listed that and mention it one by one .

1. Please make sure you have added the internet permission
2. check have you added the google-services.json file that generate from google console inside of app directory in your project

[image]

3. In your module Gradle file (usually the app/build.gradle), add the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin:

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>   // ...
> }
>
> dependencies {
>   // ...
>   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
>
>   // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
>   // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
> }
>
> // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> ```

4) add the play service class path in project level build.gridle file

> ```
> buildscript {
>     // ...
>     dependencies {
>         // ...
>         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services plugin
>     }
> }
>
> allprojects {
>     // ...
>     repositories {
>         // ...
>         google() // Google's Maven repository
>     }
> }
> ```

5) Make sure you have added those service in the AndroidManifes file inside application tag

> ```
> <service
>     android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
>     </intent-filter>
> </service>
>
> <service
>     android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
>     </intent-filter>
> </service> </application>
> ```

6) onToken refresh is called when token refresh and when install the app for the first so make sure you have deleted the app manually or clear the data

7) Make sure you have extends the FirebaseMessagingService in your  service class

[**Note** : If its not working only for specific version for example android kitkat version then try to change the fcm version.]

Comment: on kitkat device not able to get `token` `FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`

Comment: Have you checked all of the avobe issue that's I have mentioned here?

Comment: yes only on kitkat device its not working rest above kitkat its working my `FCM` version is `11.6.2`

Comment: Changing `FCM` version to `10.2.1` worked for me my targetSdkVersion is `27` and minimum is `16`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My device`(kitkat 4.4.2)` couldn't get `onTokenRefresh()` for some reason. My internet connection was perfect, google play services was up to date and all necessary contiditions for firebase to work were met. My code worked perfectly on the devices `5.0.0` and higher. To solve this issue i had to reset my device to factory settings and application started to work. I know it's tough measure but maybe it may help somebody. There must be some problems or conflict with other application, which caused `onTokenRefresh()` not to be called. Good luck!