# Firebase onTokenRefresh() is not called and notifications don't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm connecting fcm to my Android app and I have followed the documentation completely but I think I might be missing something.

I've tried reinstalling the app multiple times to try to hit `onTokenRefresh()` and it doesn't work.

I also tried sending a push notification through the Firebase portal and it never arrived.

So maybe it's something with my setup although I believe I have everything setup correctly.

I added this to the project level gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

App level gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

And outside of the app level gradle dependencies tag

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Android Manifest also has the following services

```
<service android:name=".fcm.SEFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".fcm.SEMessagingService"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Yes, my Android manifest entries are before the `</application>`

I've reviewed every single StackOverflow post regarding this issue and all of them are solved by small mistakes in the implementation that I'm not making.

Please help!

edit:

My very simple class to catch changes in the token is here

```
public class SEFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = SEFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e("token",""+refreshedToken);


    }
}
```

The main goal is being able to send notifications properly but I'm assuming that not reaching `onTokenRefresh` is the root of being unable to send a notification.

Comment: Are you confident the device or emulator you are using has a compatible version of Google Play services installed?  Look in the logcat for this warning message: `GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`.  The [FCM setup instructions recommend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play) checking for Google Play service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase onTokenRefresh() is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451395/firebase-ontokenrefresh-is-not-called)