# Google FCM getIntent not returning expected data when app is in background state

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing FCM (Firebase messaging Service) in my application. Here all seems ok except when app is in background state i am not able to extract expected notification data.

Based on concepts: There are two types of messages in FCM:

**display-messages**: These messages only work when your app is in foreground.

**data-messages**: Theses messages work even if your app is in background
When our app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray.

for handling **data-messages** your notification should have **click_action = "YOUR_ACTION"** field.

My message will like this:

```
{
 "data": {
  "body": "here is body",
  "title": "Title",
  "click_action": "YOUR_ACTION"
 },
 "to": "ffEseX6vwcM:APA91bF8m7wOF MY FCM ID 07j1aPUb"
}
```

The Activity will display the message that manifest file will like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="YOUR_ACTION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

After clicking on Notification it will redirect to my `NotificationActivity` . In my `NotificationActivity` in `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` method i am extracting message using this way:

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                Object value = bundle.get(key);
                Log.d("DATA_SENT", String.format("%s %s (%s)", key,
                        value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately in my `NotificationActivity` i am getting below message:

**google.sent_time**: 1471631793774

**from**: 50711789666

**google.message_id** 0:1471631793776823%098e508d098e508d

**collapse_key**: com.myapp.package_name

But **where is my expected notification data?**

Here is my system configuration:

**Android Studio Version**: 2.1.3

**Firebase Version**: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1

**Google Play service version** : com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1

Here are some related links:

- https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/4
- https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/47
- [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)
- [Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)
- [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Thanks in advance. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Could you please post your onMessageReceived method? I think that the problem could be in that method and for that reason your NotificationActivity is not receiving the notification data.