# Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification not received by my device

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Auth stuff in project. Today I decided to integrate FCM into my project. But I couldn't ANY notification from my Firebase console. I also tried re-download .json file but it didn't work out. Do you guys have any idea about my problem?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.yunus.ototakip">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisson.INTERNET" />

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Cihazdan Google Servislerine erişmek için izin -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- İndirilenlerin tutulması için izinler -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- OpenGL ES 2.0 Google Maps Android API v2 için gerekiyor -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"></uses-permission>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/oto_takip"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MyIntro"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AracEkle"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".InternetCon"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".IpuclariSayfasi"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TrafficActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EngineActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AidActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".AyarlarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Hesabim"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Giris"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> <!-- Check this one -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".KayitOl"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseMessageService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

**FirebaseMessageService.java**

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.oto_takip)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**FirebaseIDService.java**

```
 public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService
 {
private static final String TAG ="FirebaseIDService";
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken)
{
}
   }
```

I think the problem is not up to my MainActiviy.java but I'm gonna show it to you just in case.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private Fragment fragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
public TextView tarih;
final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
final String SHAREDPREF_DATE = "SharedPrefDate";
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private TextView textViewUserEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Giris.class));
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Navigation itemlerinin click olaylarını burada yapıyoruz.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_kullanici)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hesabim.class));

    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_hatirlatma)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AyarlarActivity.class));
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_ipucu)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,IpuclariSayfasi.class));
    }


    else if (id == R.id.nav_oyla)
    {


    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_cikis)
    {

        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Giris.class));

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

}
}
```

Comment: did you try sending directly to the FCM token ?

Comment: No, how will I do that? But I'm not sending message. I want to receive message.

Comment: Btw, I'm trying to receive message on Android emulator. Is this okay?

Comment: Take the FCM token from the app using FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() (print it in the logs so you can see it). Then use the Firebase Notification console to send a message to that specific token. In this way you can understand better what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check if you have properly configured your application to use Firebase. Add google-services plugin in the `build.gradle` file in the app directory of your project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

See this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#3) for more information.

In addition to that, [add FCM dependency](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#9). Confirm if you have this dependency in your `app/build.gradle` file.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
```

Suggested solutions in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351354/firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-not-received-by-device/37352142) might also help.