# Failed to send the FCM push notification using the REST API

Tags: android, firebase, rest, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

#### Post Request:

**URL:**

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

[image]

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=AAAAAsmF578:APA91b...90f
```

[image]

**Body:**

```
{
    "to": "fCF...ZFK", 
    "notification": {
        "title": "Foo",
        "body": "Bar"
    }
}
```

[image]

---

#### Response:

[image]

However, if I use Firebase Notification composer to send a notification on my Android device using the same FCM token `fCF...ZFK` I do receive a notification. What am I doing wrong here in the Postman? I've already tried several answers related to this on SO but didn't quite get any useful answer.

Comment: I doubt if it's the `%0A` (LF) character and it's visible in postman too... Can you manually retype the URL instead of copying from docs and try? `/fcm/send` and not `/fcm/send%0A`

Comment: @Dharmaraj You're genius! It worked, no errors now. However, I still didn't see any notification.

Comment: Did you get a successful response from the API? I'm not sure if that could be some delay in FCM then.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, I do. Here's the response `"success": 1, "failure": 0, "results": ...` but no notifications yet. I'll wait for a couple of more mins.

Comment: Yes then it maybe the delay but atleast the API URL is fixed now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [`Line Feed (LF)`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnxcar2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.qed_manual%2Ftopic%2Freference_Linefeed_character.html) character in your URL (%0A after URL encoding) which is not valid API URL. That may have been added while copying from the documentation or other source.

The URL should be `/fcm/send` instead of `/fcm/send%0A`.

Comment: Do I need to ask a separate question for not being able to see a notification using this same request?

Comment: @iDecode I'd recommend so as that might be a totally new issue which hasn't been discovered yet or perhaps an issue on client device? [Firebase Cloud Messaging notification not received by device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351354/firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-not-received-by-device) could be useful.