# How To Create Topic in FCM Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying Firebase-Notification API the service is worked perfect when i send downstream message from console to app, but how to send message to topic registered users ?

i did in android side

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("TopicName");
```

but when i try send downstream message from console to topic it's says

```
This project does not have any topics
```

EDIT :
i figured  out that after mapping the topic it's take up to 1 day to show up in Firebase Console

Comment: Hey Mohammad. If that last edit was the solution to your problem, can you post it as an answer? Self-answering is totally fine here in Stack Overflow, and will make it easier for others to find the solution (which apparently is to have patience :-) ).

Comment: Done .. sorry i thought it violate Stackoveflow policy answering your own questions in seprate answer

Comment: try this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37332514/3678308

Comment: Now New Topic available in few minutes in Firebase :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

First, given that  `IID_TOKEN` is your registration token and `TOPIC_NAME` is the topic you want to create, you need to create topic by making a **POST** request to

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME
```

And to check your created Topics make a **GET** request on this URL

```
 https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/nKctODamlM4:CKrh_PC8kIb7O...clJONHoA?details=true
```

and insert your API_KEY in your Request HEADERS

```
Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Your topic will take up to **1 day** to show up in Firebase console so for testing you can make curl request or use sofware like [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Comment: What is REGISTERATION TOKEN?

Comment: fyi: this is the exact same thing as calling `subscribeToTopic()` from a device. The logic is always the same: a topic is created when a device subscribes to it or when a server sends to it.

Comment: thats too long way

Comment: does anybody know how to unsubcribe from a topic without using batch (`https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchRemove`)?

Comment: Hey I'm stuck at this problem while creating topic in node js. Can you please tell me where's the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421040/creating-messaging-topic-on-cloud-function

Comment: @Patrick use DELETE https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME

Comment: regarding @Patrick @NickUnuchek comments, please note `DELETE` invalidates the `IID_TOKEN`, which is not necessarily desired. `batchRemove` does not.

Answer (score 67):

This is an alternate path.

If you subscribe a client app to an unexisting topic then the topic will also be created without having to call any firebase url request.

It' will also take a couple of hours to appear on Firebase Console.

By using google shared example: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging you can confirm the same.

```
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
        Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed to news topic");
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the expected delay - I'd thought that there may have been a client issue but I suspect that's the problem I'm experiencing.  Cheers.

Comment: What should I do if a topic doesn't appear even after 2 days?

Comment: @jped After 3 more days and 100 more tries and updating to 4.x branch it eventually appeared. I actually think an update solved my problem.

Comment: `news` or `/topics/news`?

Answer (score 23):

Firebase takes time to create new topic in console. In my case, new topic was created after 4 hours.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything. The function to subscribe to the topic has already been given by the OP in the question. The other one hasn't, but it is not what he asked for. Please consider editing your answer to make it correspond to the question. Thank you!

Comment: This answered my question. I was expecting it to ping instantly.

Answer (score 23):

You can create a topic with http api:

`https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME`

**1. IID_TOKEN** = Device registration token, you can find it with following command on your android device :

```
String IID_TOKEN = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

**2.TOPIC_NAME** = new a topic name

**3.Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY**. Set this parameter in the header. Look to screenshot: 
[Creating new topic via Advanced rest client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h1rM.jpg)

YOUR_API_KEY: 
[console.firebase.google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Weu2.jpg)

and send request and you will be receive http status "OK".

Then you can get infos about all your topics in your current project with following api :

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/IID_TOKEN?details=true
```

here need add Authorization key to header of request and you will be receive your topics list: [response info topics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vf6o.png)

[I recommend read this article about Instance ID/Server by Google](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server)