# FCM - Programmatically Send Push Notification To User Segments

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to send the notification to single device, topics and user segment from Firebase Console.

I want to send the push notification to a user segment. I searched a lot but I'm only getting script to send notification to Single User or Topic not to user segments.

I tried the below code

```
var client = new RestClient("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "key=mykey");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "\n\n{\"to\" : \"user-segment-name\",\n\"notification\" : {\n    \"body\" : \"test message\",\n    \"title\" : \"Portugal vs. Denmark\"\n    },\n    \"priority\":\"high\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Response.Write(response.Content);
```

And I am getting the response below

```
{"multicast_id":5837227475989925972,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Comment: Do provide some snippets on how you are sending the messages. Sample payloads would also be useful.

Comment: Is it returning a successful response?

Comment: @AL. No its not

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122646/discussion-between-hya-and-al).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that sending to user segments programatically still isn't possible. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37393535/4625829):

> But you **won't** be able to
>
> 1. send notifications to a Firebase User Identifier (UID) and
> 2. **send notifications to user segments (targeting properties & events like you can on the user console).**

It's only possible via the Firebase Console.

Comment: then the other option is topics, i used the above code to send message topics just setting "to" parameter to /topics/mytopicname. it gives me message _id but i am not receiving any push

Comment: @Hya That seems to be a different concern now. I suggest creating a different post, however, do look around the community, maybe there is already a duplicate or something similar to what you are experiencing. :)

Comment: ok i will do that! thanks for help!

Comment: Is there any way to send notifications to user segment without using console?

Comment: @Learning Depending on your use-case, you can either use Device Group Messaging or Topic Messaging. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple). Also, you must have the prerequisites to use them (the registration tokens to generate the notification id or register the device to topics).

Comment: Will check it out. Thank you!

Comment: @Learning Your welcome, you can just check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39547590/4625829) for the basic description from the docs. Cheers

Comment: Actually I think creating topic is better to get it done. I need to add `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("TopicName");` this in my android project to get it work. But I  can't update my android project again to work it out. Can I  create topic for my app in firebase console itself?

Comment: @Learning see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39382345/4625829), I've included all the links that may be useful for you.

Comment: I want an API to create a topic for my project. This http://stackoverflow.com/a/37376040/4539819 has that API explanation. But am not sure how to do it as it asks for registration token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124423/discussion-between-al-and-learning).

Comment: setup user properties, and then from user properties create audiences. then you should be able to do that.