# Firebase Notification - send to user segment vs send to topic difference

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am assigned a task to use Firebase to implement push notifications but I am kind of new this.

Looking at the documentation:

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience
```

I can't tell under what circumstances should I use `send to user segment` or `send to a topic`.

Can someone please give me some example when to use one or the other and point out the difference? Thanks ahead :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use User segements

- To typically send push notifications to a specific and limited set of devices.
- Message delivery is almost instantaneous (in my experience). Also, I haven't observed throttling as was the case earlier with GCM.

> Use Topics

- Topic or publish/subscribe mechanism is used for a comparatively larger audience and the information type is public. Examples are weather and news.
- Topics have latency (Message delivery may be throttled)

Answer (score 6):

**User Segments**

- You can only send notifications to User Segments via the [Firebase Console](https://www.console.firebase.google.com/). (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327164/4625829)).
- Limited to specific targets (from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience#send_a_message_from_the_notifications_console) you linked):

  > Select the message target. The dialog displays further options to refine the target based on whether you choose **App/App Version**, **Device Language**, or **Users in Audience**.
- As also already mentioned in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience) you linked:

  > You can target predefined user segments or **custom [audiences](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#create-an-audience) created in Firebase Analytics**.

**Topics**

- Token/device management not necessarily required.
- Unlimited number of subscribers.
- Can send to topics using the FCM API.
- Can easily subscribe/unsubscribe via the client app.

---

<sub>IMHO, if you want things to be quick and simple, go with Topic Messaging.</sub>

Comment: I always use topic messaging because it saves a lot of time. As soon as user signs in I subscribe the user to his user id and whenever I have to send a push notification to that user from server I just post message his user id. I hope that is perfect rt?

Comment: @Praveena Topics usage is a matter of preference. I don't see any issue for your use case. So I think it's okay. Just note that topics are *public* and that any other tokens may subscribe to it.

Comment: Actually this is `topics are public and that any other tokens may subscribe to it.` very important and I missed it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

first you have to save the tokens for every single device you want to send notification to, I've saved them on a table call "FCM_TOKEN", then retrieve tokens (I'm using PDO) and send them using while loop like this:

```
while($row=$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
            {
                $key = $row['Fcm_Token'];
                $headers = array(
                'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
                'Content-Type:application/json');
                $fields = array('to'=>$key,
                    'notification'=>array('title'=>$titulo, 'body'=>$mensaje,
                        'click_action'=>'com.example.witch.gtslsac_app_1_TARGET_NOTIFICATION'
                        )); 
                        $playload=json_encode($fields);
            $curl_session = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
            curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
            curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $playload);

            $result = curl_exec($curl_session);
            echo $result;   
            }
```

Don't forget to close session curl_close($curl_session);
this worked just fine for me.