# Sending FCM message with cURL, which api is recommended?

Tags: android, json, api, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know this post may be considered off-topic, I'm forced to ask, because I'm a little confused. My Android app subscribes some FCM topics and my server needs to send notifications with POST requests/json.

Looking here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging we can see Google example includes endpoint like this:

`https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send`

However, when I started looking for full api description, I found this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref and endoint is like this:

`https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

So I'm a little confused, which one is recommended to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first link to send the payload when you need to send only to some subscribed topic/channel.
Use the second link (which is mostly used) to send to devices using there registered FCM device token.

Refer to this question for more info:

[Firebase Notification - send to user segment vs send to topic difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855845/firebase-notification-send-to-user-segment-vs-send-to-topic-difference)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple

Comment: Why use first link, while I can use second one to send to single topic?

Comment: The first link is specific to the subscribed topic, you can't send a notification to those devices which are not registered to that topic, but are registered to FCM for some other notification (like a new message or any update), using the second API you can send notifications regardless of topic subscription, all you need is that the device is registered against your FCM

Comment: As far as I understand, second api allows to send to topic or to instance id, first one only to topic. So, second way is more flexible

Comment: yes, that's why second way is widely used on server side

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarify. Also first way includes project in url, so it's less flexible again