# How to make push notifications target a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using firebase web, I want to trigger a notification in a flutter app from a dashboard. In other words, I want to target the flutter app whenever I make certain changes in the dashboard using firebase cloud messaging.

Can I do that? Or do I have to write separate codes in both the flutter app and the web app?

Answer (score 0):

when you trigger a notification in a flutter app from a dashboard. You can choose which app to push (Android/iOs/web)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more on Vu Thanh's answer, you can use the User Segment in the Messaging console to select the Flutter app you want to send notifications to. You can read about a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855845/firebase-notification-send-to-user-segment-vs-send-to-topic-difference).