# Send notification from the server to user segment who installed the app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Firebase console, I saw the option to send a notification to User Segement with app "com.example" (where com.example is the app name).

As the image shows:

[image]

But how to do it from the server side using the FCM REST API:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: Are you found way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, it is [not possible to send messages to User Segments using the FCM REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327164/4625829).

As an alternative, you'll have to make use of the other ways to [send messages to multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547277/fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-send-to-multiple-devices/39547590#39547590), like simply using the `registration_ids` parameter and Topics Messaging (which I think is the most preferable for your use-case).

Here are samples on how to send this [using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143#45310143) or [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664911/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-click-action/44665817#44665817).

Comment: I cant ask my members to subscribe to topic. Whoever installs the app will start getting the notification –

Comment: I get it @SanthoshYedidi - You should just go ahead and make use of `registration_ids`. If you have more than a thousand users, you'll have to make batch requests, each having a max of 1000 registration tokens each.

Comment: Very old answer, but for future reference: Topic subscription can be done without user interaction.  Just make a POST via http to `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/[REGISTRATIONTOKEN]/rel/topics/[TOPIC]` (authorized with your server key).

Comment: @Brian The post was about using the native User Segments in Firebase. But sure using topics is a workaround if you know the actual segments and the users that must subscribe to it.

Comment: @AL.: I was responding to santhosh's that he cannot ask his members to subscribe to a topic, which I took to mean that Santhosh thought topic subscription had to be done client-side.

Answer (score 6):

i found a solution
u can subscribe your app to a specific topic for example your app package name in your FirebaseInstanceIdService class so u can send data massage like

```
 {
  "to" : "/topics/your_package_name",
  "data" : {
    "key1" : "value 1",
    "key2": "value 2",
   ...
  }
}
```

here is the code to subscribe your app to topic in  FirebaseInstanceIdService  class

```
     public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        private final String TAG="your_tag";
        @Override
        public void onTokenRefresh() {


        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your_app_package_name");
        }
}
```

its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to send a message to the topic .. All the members subscribed to a topic will get your message ..

Just check out the link ..

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Comment: I cant ask my members to subscribe to topic. Whoever installs the app will start getting the notification

Comment: Asking About FCM and replying for GCM. Irrelevant answer

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi when user install the app call the subscribe to topic method so they will automatically subscribe to the topic

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe your users depending on the OS

topic: "android" for android user

topic: "iOS" for iOS user

(or whatever name you want)

and then send to that topic...

Answer (score -1):

Make a post call to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send with  following parameters:-

Headers:-

Content-Type--application/json

Authorization--key={your server key}

Body:-

```
{
    "data": {
        "my_custom_key" : "my_custom_value",

        "message" : "notification message"
     },
    "registration_ids": ["device_token1,device_token2,.........."]
}
```

EDIT:-

Basically what you need to do is ,whenever u need to send notification you have to call this POST method from your server side and your app will automatically get a call in OnMessageReceived . You can handle that as:-

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        Map<String, String> data=remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + data.toString());
        String value=data.get("my_custom_key");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + value);
        String msg=data.get("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + msg);

        sendNotification(msg,value,remoteMessage.getSentTime());
    }
```

Comment: `"registration_ids": ["device_token1,device_token2,.........."]`: I want to send to any user who installed the app. Refer the updated question. From firebase console using user segment option i can send without need of device token. Because my notifications are generic

Comment: when user installs your app , a refresh token is generated. send this token to your server , this is device token

Comment: and you can save the tokens in your server

Comment: From Firebase console, you can only send notification to user when app is in foreground. To send notification in background or when app is closed, u need to have a post call

Comment: yes, thats the android part.But i am looking how to send to user-segment from the server side. I have implemented the foreground part already. the notifications are getting recieved. But till now i using firebase console. NOw i want to shift to a server from where i want to send notification

Comment: if your backend is in php then you can refer to https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-tutorial-using-firebase/

Comment: @santhosh one think i can think is that silently register the user for a topic say "generic" when they install the app.so all your user's will be subscribed to it.and then send your generic notifications to this topic