# How to send FCM to entire app using ARC?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I cant find any information regarding how to target just the app, I don't have any topics and I don't want to merely target a single user.

The documentation states that a `to` is optional but I just receive a missingregistration error:

> This parameter specifies the recipient of a message.
>
> The value can be a device's registration token, a device group's notification key, or a single topic (prefixed with /topics/). To send to multiple topics, use the condition parameter.

This is my current setup:

[image: 1]

Removing the `to` field just gives me an error and the message is merely `to`.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to send to a specific app (or to any user segments) when using the FCM REST API (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327164/4625829)). This option is only available when sending the notifications through the Firebase Notifications Console.

The [`to`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) parameter is considered *optional*, but in reality, you need to have either `to` or `registration_ids` to specify the target for your message payload. So not having a valid `to` or `registration_ids` is returning you a [`MissingRegistration`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) error as expected.

Comment: So is there a way of sending data via a notification that will register on the app even if the app is closed? Thats why I'm looking into this solution

Comment: Hey James. I'm not sure I follow. Your use-case is possible for FCM (sending messages even if the app is closed could be a bit broad -- see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829)). It's just that you need to store the registration tokens first, before being able to send a message to the users.

Answer (score 0):

@James you can send notifications to user segments (targeting properties & events like you can on the user console). Through postman you'll have to store FCM/GCM registration ids (push tokens) yourself or use FCM topics to subscribe users