# Send Firebase Cloud Messaging notification to users by user property

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send out an FCM message to a specific set of users (or really, a single user) based on a specific user property but looking through the [FCM HTTP API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) I can't seem to find a way to do that. I can send to users via topics, registration tokens, and device group notification keys, but I don't have any of that infrastructure set up in the near term. I know this functionality exists as you can send such a message via the UI, but I'm not seeing how to do it in the API documentation as yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no parameter that you could use to specify a user property (or even for [user segments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327164/4625829)) that will serve as a target for the FCM API to send the message to.

As you've already searched, the only targets possible are single/multiple registration tokens (`to` and `registration_ids`), topics, conditions, and device groups (`notification_key`).

The option you're looking for is currently only available when using the Notifications Console.

Comment: Too bad, was hoping that I was just missing something...thanks for confirming though.

Comment: Have you please an idea about if multiple userProperty values (of the same userProperty key) can be associated to the same user (device)?

Comment: @NeAS I think you're expecting too much from FCM. With that use-case, you'd have to implement a profile system on your own and tie the token to it.

Comment: @AL. thanks for the answer. So the conclusion is that a device can be linked to one value of a specific user property. Isn't it?