# Send FCM Token to Specific App of a Project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have created one project in my Firebase Account. In this project, I have added two android apps.

Now, while sending push notification through Firebase console, I see the option of selecting my individual app as shown below

[image]

But, while sending notification through Postman, I don't know how can I send notification to only a particular app?

Should I create two individual project for both my apps, so that the server key is different?

But, I feel there should be a way to send notification without creating multiple projects for multiple apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sending notifications to user segments is not available programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327164/4625829) i.e. not available when using the API.

A workaround you could use is Topics Messaging, creating a topic for the specific app and subscribe the corresponding users.