# Send a Firebase message to a specific app on all devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

On the GUI of **`Firebase`** Console, I could send a message to a specific app as you see in the screenshot below. But what is the **`JSON`** equivalent of it?

```
Address: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Method: POST
Content Type: application/json
Authorization: key = the key on the cloud messaging page.
```

[image: Firebase console]

Comment: I got a hint at the word "user segment" after posting this question (why didn't I notice it before...?) and searched Google for it. I have found an exiting answer that says [it is only possible on the Firebase Console, not programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326251/fcm-programatically-send-push-notification-to-user-segments).