# No notification sound when sending notification from firebase in android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification from firebase to my Android Application. but when my app is in background firebase onMessageReceived method is not called instead firebase send notification to system for showing notification in system tray.
notification appears in system tray but no sound for notification even i have allowed notification sound for my app in system settings.

what I can do to play notification sound when notification received from firebase.

This is how I am sending notification from firebase to my app [Blogpost link](http://developine.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-android-tutorial/).

[How to Add firebase in your Android Application](http://developine.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-android-tutorial/)

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325051/notification-icon-with-the-new-firebase-cloud-messaging-system/37490005#37490005)..

Comment: make sure to check notification settings for that app

Answer (score 125):

In the notification payload of the notification there is a sound key.

From the official documentation its use is:

> Indicates a sound to play when the device receives a notification.
>   Supports default or the filename of a sound resource bundled in the
>   app. Sound files must reside in /res/raw/.

Eg:

```
{
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",

    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon",
      "sound" : "mySound"
    }
  }
```

If you want to use default sound of the device, you should use: `"sound": "default"`.

See this link for all possible keys in the payloads:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

For those who don't know firebase handles notifications differently when the app is in background. In this case the onMessageReceived function is not called.

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification
>   messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the
>   app launcher by default. This includes messages that contain both
>   notification and data payload. In these cases, the notification is
>   delivered to the device's system tray, and the data payload is
>   delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Comment: if you want to use default sound of device, you should use:

"sound" : "default"

Comment: @TranVo thanks for points out that "default" value plays the default sound of the device, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: in the notification am getting response for which screen redirect key if app in foreground and click notification working fine if in backgroung notification clicked open launcher activity onMessageReceived how to handle please help me for both background and foreground handlings

Comment: I tried all the possible ways but not able have that default sound or sound from setting my own tone and also not getting vibration what may be the reason

Comment: I have done .setSound(defaultSoundUri), but I am not getting notification sound, when send from firebase

Comment: So how can I disable the sound of the notification?

Comment: I assume not including the sound parameter should do it, but please verify

Comment: This won't work with the new APIs. ```Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "badge" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.``` Also you're using TypeScript (you should be) it will flag this on compilation before you submit it to Firebase

Comment: any way to disable the notification sound? Excluding the sound attribute doesn't work, the sound is still enabled

Comment: I have the sound but no vibration, any idea?

Comment: Has the new Notification Channel system obsoleted this API for older devices, or does it still work for older devices? I've been trying to make custom sounds show up for a Nougat device but I just seem to get the default chime sound effect no matter what I enter in "sound" or "soundName." I've tried "mysoundeffect.wav" and "mysoundeffect" with no luck.

Comment: I want a feature in app where user can disable all notifications sound. But how can I achieve this. Because if sound is ON in first time then how can we disable it on notification when app is in terminated state.

Answer (score 31):

Try this

```
{
    "to" : "DEVICE-TOKEN",

    "notification" : {
      "body"  : "NOTIFICATION BODY",
      "title" : "NOTIFICATION TITILE",
      "sound" : "default"
    }
  }
```

@note for custom notification sound:->  `"sound" : "MyCustomeSound.wav"`

Comment: So where do you put that file? in raw? assets?

Comment: Not assets folder, create a newfolder under res, call it raw. Then copy and paste your wav or mp3 file to that folder. @HamzehSoboh

Comment: I put sound into /res/raw/my_sound.mp3 in the Android app then call API with "sound": "my_sound.mp3". Not working, just default sound was played :( Anyone like me ?

Comment: Oh, I make it worked. Using Android Notification Channel, More detail here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142155/custom-sound-in-firebase-push-notification

Answer (score 28):

[image: adavaced options]
select **advanced options** when **Write a message**, and choose sound **activated**
[image: choose activated]

this is My solution

Comment: @KongJing in Android 8 and above, it always have sound no matter setting of Firebase console. Do you know a way to prevent sound completely?

Comment: I am sorry to see this so late, I can't solve this problem.@Think Twice Code Once

Answer (score 15):

The `onMessageReceived` method is fired only when app is in foreground or the notification payload only contains the data type.

From the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

> For downstream messaging, FCM provides two types of payload:
>   **notification** and **data**.
>
> For **notification** type, FCM automatically displays the message to
>   end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notifications have a
>   predefined set of user-visible keys.
>   For **data** type, client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.
>
> **Use notifications** when you want **FCM to handle** displaying a
>   notification on your client app's behalf. **Use data** messages when you
>   want your **app to handle** the display or process the messages on your
>   Android client app, or if you want to send messages to iOS devices
>   when there is a direct FCM connection.

Further down the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messages-with-both-notification-and-data-payloads)

> **App behaviour** when receiving messages that include both notification
>   and data payloads depends on whether the app is in the background or
>   the foreground—essentially, whether or not it is active at the time of
>   receipt.
>   **When in the background**, apps receive the notification payload
>   in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the
>   user taps on the notification.
>   **When in the foreground**, your app receives a message object with both payloads available.

If you are using the firebase console to send notifications, the payload will always contain the notification type. You have to use the Firebase API to send the notification with only the data type in the notification payload. That way your app is always notified when a new notification is received and the app can handle the notification payload.

If you want to play notification sound when app is in background using the conventional method, you need to [add the sound parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) to the notification payload.

Comment: nah, it is also called when the app is closed but u should allowe auto start of the app.

Answer (score 11):

I was also having a problem with notifications that had to emit sound, when the app was in foreground everything worked correctly, however when the app was in the background the sound just didn't come out.

The notification was sent by the server through FCM, that is, the server mounted the JSON of the notification and sent it to FCM, which then sends the notification to the apps. Even if I put the sound tag, the sound does not come out in the backgound.

[image]

Even putting the sound tag it didn't work.

[image]

After so much searching I found the solution on a github forum. I then noticed that there were two problems in my case:

1 - It was missing to send the channel_id tag, important to work in API level 26+

[image]

2 - In the Android application, for this specific case where notifications were being sent directly from the server, I had to configure the channel id in advance, so in my main Activity I had to configure the channel so that Android knew what to do when notification arrived.

In JSON sent by the server:

```
   {
  "title": string,
  "body": string,
  "icon": string,
  "color": string,
  "sound": mysound,

  "channel_id": videocall,
  //More stuff here ...
 }
```

In your main Activity:

```
 @Background
    void createChannel(){
            Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.app_note_call);
            NotificationChannel mChannel;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel("videocall", "VIDEO CALL", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GRAY);
                mChannel.enableLights(true);
                mChannel.setDescription("VIDEO CALL");
                AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                        .build();
                mChannel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes);

                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
    }
```

This finally solved my problem, I hope it helps someone not to waste 2 days like I did. I don't know if it is necessary for everything I put in the code, but this is the way. I also didn't find the github forum link to credit the answer anymore, because what I did was the same one that was posted there.

Answer (score 10):

With HTTP v1 API it is different

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages)

Example:

```
{
 "message":{
    "topic":"news",
    "notification":{
       "body":"Very good news",
       "title":"Good news"
    },
    "android":{
       "notification":{
          "body":"Very good news",
          "title":"Good news",
          "sound":"default"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how to write this in php ?

Comment: @Tabishkhan `$this->message['message']['android']['notification']['sound'] = "default";`

Comment: What about ios sounds?

Comment: @Scilef Please refer to: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages. The member corresponding to `android` for iOS is `apns`. Inside `apns` you need a `payload` member, and inside that you need an `aps` member which corresponds to the usual aps payload for iOS as per: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification?language=objc

Answer (score 10):

You need to make sure your system enable sound notifications for your app, some devices like **Xiaomi** disable this option by default, so you will not hear notifications sound until you go to:

Settings > Notifications > (search for your app and click on it name)...

Then enable (Allow Sound) option As shown in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

do like this

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    //codes..,.,,

    Uri sound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(sound);

}
```

Comment: onMessageReceived is not called when app is in background. actually this is problem which i am facing

Comment: did you call this(Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext()); ) from main activity

Comment: no i havent. but now I am playing notification answer from isl worked for me.

Comment: please tell me builder is generated error please define builder

Comment: builder is notificationcompat builder

Comment: but I still not getting sound when app is in background.

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
  public  void buildPushNotification(Context ctx, String content, int icon, CharSequence text, boolean silent) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Activity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1410, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), //large drawable);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setLargeIcon(bm)
            .setContentTitle(content)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if(!silent)
       notificationBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

> and in onMessageReceived, call it

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    Log.d("Msg", "Message received [" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() + "]");

    buildPushNotification(/*your param*/);
}
```

or follow [KongJing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5932895/kongjing), Is also correct as he says, but you can use a Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to play notification sound even if I send it from firebase console. To do that you just need to add key "sound" with value "default" in advance option.

Comment: Your Idea is work But I have required TO change Notification image when Phone is locked How can i change please Help me

Comment: I am try You previous Idea But Not work Please Help It is so urgent

Comment: How can we push notification with no sound i.e. no sound when a notification received on device.