# No sound when message sent from firebase console when app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

My code is ditto same as provided by fcm docs I am recieving notification when app is closed without using intent extras or any php code.

when app is in foreground onMessageRecieved() method gets invoked so i get default sound but when app is in background or closed i dont get sound.

i am using one phone and firebase console to send message thats it no php scripts or http requests

my phone setting has max volume for notification

Comment: Refered Only this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No notification sound when sending notification from firebase in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959588/no-notification-sound-when-sending-notification-from-firebase-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

From your firebase console (Notifications), go to Advanced options > Sound > Enable - before sending every message. Thus you'll get sound even if your app is in background. Here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much Sir such a silly problem sorry ><

Comment: Hello, do you know how can we send a specific sound from the FCM console when the app is closed?