# Android ; Sound not playing in FCM push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am sending data messages from our app server calling firebase api to users.Users are receiving the notifications but sound is not playing when notification arrives.

here is the code

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    sendNotification(remoteMessage); 
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    Log.d(TAG, message.getData().toString());

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, defaultSoundUri);
    r.play();

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(message.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(Html.fromHtml(message.getData().get("body")))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
//                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        saveMessage(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

what could be the problem???

Comment: you can check for your solution in this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959588/no-notification-sound-when-sending-notification-from-firebase-in-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: this means i need to send the parameter "sound" :"default or custom" in the data message sent to the user.

Comment: Have you tried setting the defaults? i.e. `setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set sound on notification builder. 
So, Try with uncomment below line.

```
.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
```

and comment below lines.

```
//Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, defaultSoundUri);
//r.play();
```

If you want to play notification sound when app is in background, you need to [add the sound parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) to the notification payload.

Supports **"default"** or the **filename** of a sound resource bundled in the app. Sound files must reside in `/res/raw/`

Comment: i first tried .setSound(defaulturi) but still it wasn't playing...Do i need to set Sound parameter in the data message sent to the user..

Comment: i am sending data messages..even if my app is in foreground sound is not playing...