# No custom sound with Android Firebase Notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.1-oreo

I am using Firebase push notifications in my Android App. I can send correctly notification with custom icon, but I have not managed to play my custom sound. I always get the default sound of my device.

```
{
    "registration_ids": "myToken",
    "notification": {
        "body": "my body",
        "title": "my title",
        "icon": "ic_notification",
        "sound": "mysound.mp3" // I tried "mysound", "mysound.wav"...

    },
    "priority": "high"

}
```

The custom sound is located in /res/raw

I have been able to play my custom sound with `onMessageReceived` and Firebase data message **but not with Firebase notification message**.

My android device is Xiaomi Mi A1 and Oreo 8.1., also tried with Xiaomi Mi A2 with same result.

I tried with php and curl, with node.js... always same problem, I get my default sound.

**UPDATE**

With this code for node.js does not work either:

```
var registrationToken = 'xxxxxx';

var message = {

    notification: {
      title: 'my title',
      body: 'my body',
    },
    android: {
      ttl: 3600 * 1000,
      notification: {
        color: '#ff0000',
        sound: 'mysound.mp3'
      }
    }, 
    token: registrationToken

};
```

Comment: Please refer to [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#defining_the_message) when structuring your message payload.  In my experience, the only thing you should have in `notification` is `{ "body", "payload" }`.  Structure other settings in the platform specific sections *(e.g. for sound, place the sound in `message.android.notification.sound`)*

Comment: I use this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. For Android 8.0 and higher it's necessary to create a notification channel in your App:

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel('my_id', name, importance);
```

(more info: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#java)

Then when you send the notification:

```
var registrationToken = 'xxxxxx';

var message = {

    notification: {
      title: 'my title',
      body: 'my body',
    },
    android: {
      ttl: 3600 * 1000,
      notification: {
        color: '#ff0000',
        sound: 'mysound.mp3',
        channel_id: 'my_id' // important to get custom sound
      }
    }, 
    token: registrationToken

};
```

Comment: Is there anything else you did to get it working?  This does still does not work for me.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830367/custom-sound-for-android-push-notification-not-working-fcm

Answer (score 4):

I was also looking for the solution to custom sound for firebase notification in the android, And I have solved this problem through Notification Channel.

I have created one notification channel with custom sound, that sound plays after receiving notification in the application background state.

You can refer following links of the notification channel.

https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

You need to put your mp3 file at **/res/raw/** path.

Please find the code.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class); // If you are writting code in fragment
```

OR

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NotificationManager.class); // If you are writting code in Activity
```

createNotificationChannel function

```
private void createNotificationChannel() { 
 Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sample); //Here is FILE_NAME is the name of file that you want to play 
// Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because 
// the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library if 
(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
 { 
    CharSequence name = "mychannel"; 
    String description = "testing"; 
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT; 
    AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder() 
     .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION) 
     .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM) 
     .build(); 
   NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("cnid", name, importance); 
   channel.setDescription(description); 
   channel.enableLights(true); channel.enableVibration(true); 
   channel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes); 
   notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel); 
  } 
};

createNotificationChannel();
```

To achieve this you need to pass **android_channel_id** property in the firebase notification request object.

```
{
 "notification": {
 "body": "this is testing notification",
 "title": "My App",
 "android_channel_id": "cnid"
 },
 "to": "token"
}
```

**Note** - If you create a notification channel once then you can't change the sound. You have to create a new notification channel with the new name with your desired sound.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#android-specific_fields), include the sound in notification object under android object. Give name of the sound file in sound value. The sound files must reside in **/res/raw/** . Below is a Node.js example:-

```
  var message = {
  notification: {
    title: 'sample title',
    body: 'Hello, its Tuesday.',
  },
  android: {
    ttl: 3600 * 1000,
    notification: {
      icon: 'my_icon',
      color: '#f45342',
      sound: 'filename.mp3',
    },
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        badge: 42,
      },
    },
  },
  topic: 'industry-tech'
};
```

Comment: Are you getting notification when app is in background using **notification** payload?

Comment: Yes, I get notification when app is in background, but I get default sound

Answer (score 0):

**Try Enabling  Sound From Firebase Console**

For More Info Just Look at this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304089/9024123

may be this should be problem and also try removing '.mp3' in sound element and make it like

```
"sound":"mySound"
```

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing the same issue. I always got the default sound but i fixed it as follows . I am using FCM-push (node module) https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-push

```
var message = {  
to : device_token,
collapse_key : '<insert-collapse-key>',
// data : {
//     '<random-data-key1>' : '<random-data-value1>',
//     '<random-data-key2>' : '<random-data-value2>'
// },
notification : {
    title : 'Title ',
    body : 'some Body',
    sound : 'notification' // my .ogg file in /res/raw
},
android: {
sound: 'notification' // my .ogg file name in /res/raw
}
};
```

I have not tried it with mp3 or wav and in your question it seems you have not tried with .ogg file ( though i doubt if it has anything to do with audio format but you can try)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps :
In my case i tried with the above approach and it did not worked, whenever i was checking in the onMessageReceived (for debug purpose) the channel id

```
Log.e(TAG, "Message Notification channel id: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getChannelId());
```

i always got 'null'.

So reading the documentation from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

I found out that i was using the wrong key for the channel id in the json.

**Instead of 'channel_id' key try to use 'android_channel_id' key like this**

```
"notification": {
        "body": "Body of Your Notification",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification",
        "android_channel_id": "channelId",
        "icon": "myIcon"
    }
```

If i use it like that it works as expected, custom sound (from res/raw) is played

PS: in my case i set my sound on the channelId when i created it

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I made when trying this was I didn't change the the channel id although I updated the Json and modified the code. My channel was always bound to the device sound. Just after I updated to a different channel id my code started working. Custom sound is now playing for both foreground and background

Following is the JSON which worked for me

```
{
"to" : "token"
,
"notification": {
    "title":"Server Notification Title",
    "body":"Notification Body",
    "sound":"sound.wav",
    "android_channel_id": "ch1"
},
"priority": "high"
}
```

The code

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "ch1")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody().toString())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if(soundUri != null){
            // Changing Default mode of notification
            notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            // Creating an Audio Attribute
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .build();

            // Creating Channel
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ch1","App Name",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes);
            channel.enableLights(true); channel.enableVibration(true);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```