# Custom FCM notification sound for unity android

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my unity project I want play custom sound when I get firebase cloud message, not system default sound.
So after I followed other answers my message looks like,

```
{
    "to": "some_key",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Title",
        "android_channel_id": "2",
        "body": "Body",
        "sound": "custom_sound.wav"
    }
}
```

and I placed `custom_sound.wav` in `Asset/Plugins/Android/res/raw`. When I unzip my .apk, I can find my sound file is in right location.

But it keeps playing system default sound. Even after I remove sound field. Is there any other thing should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: a quick tip when debugging. If you select "Export Project", you can open the generated Gradle project with Android Studio:
[image: Build Settings window open with "Export Project" selected]
Occasionally you have to update the gradle wrapper, but it helps a ton debug things like "is my sound file in res/raw" without having to decompress your APK and poke around.

I think that the issue you're running into now is that sounds are now associated with NotificationChannels (as of Android O) rather than individual notifications, as noted by [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929138/no-custom-sound-with-android-firebase-notification) expressing a similar issue. Since this isn't exposed via the Unity SDK.

Fortunately, you can add a channel with [Unity.Notifications.Android](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.0/api/Unity.Notifications.Android.AndroidNotificationChannel.html).

It should be as simple as creating a new
`public AndroidNotificationChannel(string id, string title, string description, Importance importance)`
with your `id` set to `"2"` (to match your sample notification above. Since this is a string, I would recommend giving this a better name :D).

Then you can call `RegisterNotificationChannel` with that channel you create as your parameter.

For example, to get your notification above to work, I believe you can write:

```
var notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("2", "Channel 2 (working title)", "This is the 2nd channel", Importance.Default);
AndroidNotificationCenter.RegisterNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

Let me know if this helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Thanks for the answer and tip! But sadly, my app still playing default sound. Other changes I made via `AndroidNotificationChannel` works(like importance), but there is no sound field in `AndroidNotificationChannel`. So it seems that Unity built-in notification doesn't support custom sound right now, right?