# Ionic 6 Capacitor iOS FCM Notifications with Custom or Default Sound

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor, ionic6, capacitor-plugin

In my `Ionic 6 Capacitor App` I'm implementing `FCM push notifications` for both, Android and iOS. I'm using Capacitor plugins https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm and https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications

For Android, I was able to customize notifications (custom sound, creating a `NotificationChannel` in `MainActivity.java`).

But for iOS I just get the notifications but no default sound at least is reproduced. I do not find documentation on how to do that or any confirmation about if it is possible or not for iOS.

I'm firing my FCM notifications using the Java SDK, and there I tried setting the Message options `setSound("default")` and `setDefaultSound(true)` but did not work.

In official documentation, I don't see any sound options related information for iOS specifically. I also took a look to the fcm Github repository example https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm/tree/master/example but I don't see any sound related code or options.

I appreciate your time to review this issue. If someone have configured custom or default sound for iOS, please let me know about your experience configuring or coding that.

Comment: have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142155/custom-sound-in-firebase-push-notification

Comment: Hi @inkredusk Yes, I took a look at the question but it is for Android devices. I'm looking how to reproduce a sound for iOS devices. I'm not using legacy SDK, I'm using up to date FCM Java SDK.