# How to add sound for notification in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, push-notification

I tried many ways but it didn't work when adding sound in notification push from FCM.
So How to add sound for notification in vuejs?

Comment: see this, it might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/37959847/9543351

Comment: @DevinY That link only support for android. Anything for VueJS?