# Firebase Notification white circle issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've a problem with `Firebase Notification`, If I send notification when app is running on screen the notification show correctly like this:

[image]

[image]

Than if I send notification when app in running on background, the notification appears like this:

[image]

[image]

This is my `FirebaseMessagingService` class

```
    public class AppFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        int icon = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? R.drawable.ic_video_label_white_24dp: R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notificationBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bug in Firebase which is not resolved yet. Link here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37332514/1507602

Another alternative is to not to use Firebase console to send notification, instead use POST API, that way your notification will be delivered directly to `onMessageReceived()` where you can create your own Notification.

*To send a data payload message you have to make a curl request:*

### HTTP POST Request

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

You can get the server key (AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA), from firebase console: **Your project -> settings -> Project settings -> Cloud messaging -> Server Key**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can send message to all user with one instance?

Comment: Yes, you can - just use Topic Messaging for this

Comment: Thanks guys, I still hope it will be solved as soon as this bug

Answer (score 3):

The reason, why it is happening is way how Firebase Notifications are working, and different behavior, when app is in foreground and different when in background:

1. Foreground - here is compatibility, with this, what was in past and GCM - you are fully controlling and your code from AppFirebaseMessagingService is executed
2. Background - in this case system/library is responsible for displaying message, and is using for this main icon of app. If you have any data in data node, then it is passed as intent to main activity of your app (after user will press notification)

Due to this - I decided in my app not using it as:
     1. I cannot control it
     2. Is used default icon of app (that in my case was also looking like yours - rounded
     3. I cannot make additional things with this (in my case I was also showing image + adding action, and with Firebase notifications - I
    cannot make this, when app is in background)