# Notification icon is greyed out

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-icons

I created an image in a 96x96 size, gave padding of 4px on all sides following this [information](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/).

Then I used [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) to generate icons for different screens. But when I used these in my Notification Builder it is showing a grey box. Where am I doing wrong?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9hAu.png) is my image. Unable to display it here as background is transparent and image is white in color. Please download to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. all my colors are white over transparent png, i still get plain white square on it. I checked the drawable folder have already generated 12 corresponding ic_stat_name.png file and they look as expected. But when i send notification the icon still appear white square.

I found the solution
[Notification Icon with the new Firebase Cloud Messaging system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325051/notification-icon-with-the-new-firebase-cloud-messaging-system)

I use firebase notification which, according to the above source, will use the launcher icon instead of my expected ic_stat_name.png for notification

Comment: I am using API, not console to send notifications. My problem is with the design aspects not handling notifications.

Comment: This answer actually helped me. The `<meta-info>` tags in the manifest were the issue.