# Firebase notification style

Tags: firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I use firebase with cURL. I wonder how to use big image style and put big image url to the "notification" section in json file.

My file looks like that:

```
{
"to" : "my_device_id",

"notification" : {
  "body" : "great match!",
  "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
  "icon" : "ic_notify",
  "click_action" : "FIREBASE_NOTIFICATION"
}
"data" : {
  "data1" : "data1_content"
}
}
```

I know how to put icon and click_action. I'm looking for keys for style and big picture content.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I just realized how looks firebase RemoteMessage.Notification class. There are no getters like "getBigPicture". It's probably impossible to do what I want, but I leave this question on account of firebase's newer versions (where they add this feature, I suppose.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible with Firebase Notifications. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325051/notification-icon-with-the-new-firebase-cloud-messaging-system/37332514#37332514

Answer (score 1):

FCM does not currently support the large notification style, and by extension does not currently support the large image for notifications.

Comment: I had written it before your answer.