# Android notification has a color icon instead of being turned white

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Android app uses Firebase Cloud Messaging for notifications. When notifications come in, the icon isn't turned white like the other icons.

[image]

I'm using `targetSdkVersion 23`.

I have this in my manifest:

```
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```

With a PNG file at `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/notification_icon.png`.

How can I get the icon to behave normally?

Comment: Can you share your icon xml code?

Comment: Updated the question. It's a PNG file, not SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Will Jones, the solution was to use a SVG file and convert it to XML using this: http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/. I then copied the file to `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/notification_icon.xml` and deleted the old PNG file.

The icon now renders properly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the icon in the SVG designer. Have you assigned a colour to it or is it showing white there?

Comment: It's a color image, but even if I turn it white, it's not the same shade of white as the other ones, and it doesn't invert on a white background (so it is completely invisible on a white background)

Comment: Try converting it to an SVG, I can't say I've ever used PNGs for these icons.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37332514/5544859).

then set your resource to white: android:resource="@color/google_white"

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [Notification icon generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but try to add this to your manifest

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/notification_icon_color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have an ionic project, so the answer of [@Flavien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50705271/3026105) is correct but instead of:

```
android/app/src/main/res/drawable/notification_icon.xml
```

You need to write without the .xml suffix, like this:

```
android/app/src/main/res/drawable/notification_icon
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
      android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_no_bg_small" />
```

You should offer a png with transparent background.