# Android notification background icon color

Tags: android

I have a [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8JOf.png) which I want to put for notificaiton. Now I want to change the background of the icon. Example - Background with circle and N should be white.

Like this one - [Example icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc4J5.png)

I tried to give background color but it is not working.

I tired this way icon but it is not converting the background color - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40405349/3774906

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.