# Android mipmap icons as status (notification) bar icon

Tags: android, android-icons

So the Android documentation says that app icons (mipmap) is converted into to notification bar icon by putting a white filter on all pixels not transparent.
The problem is I need white color in the icon (when it's on the phone screen full size) but the white should be removed when shown in the status (notification) bar.

Since there isn't a separate image for notification icons I am a bit lost on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly makes you think there is no separate image for notification icons? Nofication Builder https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html should let you set whatever notification icon you want :)

Comment: Where should I do the building. Should I create a new builider in the onMessageReceived method in the service or once in the main activities onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

The awnser to my question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37332514/2984127).

I will bring it out here as well:

> If you are dealing with a Remote Message like firebase notification
>   then you dont need to use any notification builder to change the icon
>   or the background color but you can just specify the icon in the
>   AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/google_blue" />
```

Note please that this can be done from FB SDK v9.8 and up though.