# How to customize Firebase InAppMessaging modal/dialog UI?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I have read Firebase In-App-Messaging [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/customize-messages?authuser=0&platform=android) about **Modify message displays** section.

But, I still confuse how to customize modal/dialog UI? is it feasible to do that?

I want to edit font type of the text inside modal/dialog.

Comment: Post your code what you tried?

Comment: This is a good question. I would love to know the solution for this one too.

Comment: I think this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41031536/1906738