# How to set a bigger icon in Firebase app notification?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi i am implementing Push Notifications in Android using Firebase. Now, there is a small icon showing inside one circle. I need it to show in bigger size. Please see the image. And here is my code,

```
            android:id="@+id/relativeNotification"

            android:layout_width="192dp"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <com.inspius.coreapp.widget.TintableImageView
                android:layout_width="192dp"
                android:layout_height="192dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                app:tint="@color/custom_icon_video_detail_selector" />
```

How do i set large icon from this small icon?

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: could you add your code to show the notification ?

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be done by overriding the default settings.

In your application manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```

Use your icon instead of `@drawable/notification_icon`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37332514/4409113)

Hope that helps

**Update:** Also, Have a look:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/4#issuecomment-221344318

> The icon parameter can be used to specify a drawable within your app.
>   If you want to use R.drawable.foo, just pass foo.

Here is the `icon` parameter documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do the same thing. Overriding "handleIntent" method worked for me. I guess removing the super.handleIntent(intent) made this work. Then we can build our own notification to set the large icon. Both foreground and background cases would call this method. Something like this:

```
public class YourMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // super.handleIntent(intent);

        // get intent codes....

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        Notification notification = builder
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourLargeIcon))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yourSmallIcon)
                .setContentTitle("yourTitle")
                .setContentText("yourText")
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(111, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working anymore:
error: handleIntent(Intent) in MyFirebaseMessagingService cannot override handleIntent(Intent) in FirebaseMessagingService
overridden method is final

Comment: This still works for me. handleIntent() is always called, foreground and background. So inside the intent I also included the title / body. No need for onMessageReceived() anymore.

Don't call .super otherwise you'll get a double notification.

Answer (score 2):

See You can customize your firebase notification **only when your app is in foreground.**

Your notification will be caught in **onMessageReceived** method of **FirebaseMessagingService** service

To Customize your notification when your app is in foreground.

Put Icon From App Drawable Folder

```html
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icons);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Put Icon From API "icon" tag

```html
String name = remoteMessage.getNotification().getIcon();
URL url_value = new URL(name);
Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setLargeIcon(mIcon1)
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```