# push notification large icon is not displayed in some devices

Tags: firebase, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase for push notification .I am displaying LargeIcon and expanded image in the notification tray. In some devices the large icon is not coming. Showing blank.
My code for notificaitonBuilder is :

```
var notificationBuilder = new   Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                    .SetContentTitle(App.NotificationData.Title)
                    .SetContentText(App.NotificationData.MessageBody)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .SetSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                if(image!=null)
                {
                bigImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(image, (int)(192), (int)(192), false);
                image = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(image, (int)(48), (int)(48), false);
                //image = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(image, (int)(image.Width * multiplier), (int)(image.Height * multiplier), false);
                notificationBuilder.SetLargeIcon(image);
                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479579/how-to-set-a-bigger-icon-in-firebase-app-notification

Comment: Which devices are not working? Since the code could work on some device, the code is fine.