# Unable change push notification icon in notification panel

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am trying to change the push notification icon when I send a notification from firebase console(while app is in background). I've added the following code to my manifest file:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/custom_notification_icon" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/color_accent" />
```

Unfortunately, it is still showing the launcher icon. How to solve this?

**NB:** I am using Firebase SDK 10.2.0

Additionally, How can I customize the *statusbar icon* when a notification has come ? Please help me guys.

Comment: Try making custom notification using the onMessageReceived method from the FirebaseMessagingService , but remember send the data in data payload, not in notification.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Is there another way to change the notification icon without using `NotificationBuilder` ? The above code works for many people. But what is wrong with mine ? May be the sdk version or something ?

Comment: This is so disappointing. SO has been so helpful to me but no response in  new questions which is not very common. Is it becoming dead ??!!

Comment: here is a good thread that might give you a few good ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325051/notification-icon-with-the-new-firebase-cloud-messaging-system  ...there is mention of using FirebaseMessagingService which might be worth looking into

Comment: Still no answers D: