# Error: adaptive icons with no fallback drawable for FCM notifications, can cause irreversible crash on Android Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo, pusher

When developing an Android app today, I got the following error message in the logcat:

> You are targeting Android Oreo and using adaptive icons without having
>   a fallback drawable set for FCM notifications. 
>       This can cause a irreversible crash on devices using Oreo.
>       To learn more about this issue check: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68716460

It took me a while to track down the meaning and what to do, so I am adding an answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an error generated by the [Pusher Beams Android SDK](https://pusher.com/docs/beams/reference/android) warning about a bug in Android 8.0 Oreo. See [this article](https://blog.pusher.com/upgrade-app-android-oreo-avoid-factory-reset/) for more information about it. Also, check out [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325051/notification-icon-with-the-new-firebase-cloud-messaging-system).

As mentioned in the above links and [here in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive), to solve the problem, add the following `meta-data` to your AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest ...>
    <application...>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_default_notification" />
       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

where `ic_default_notification` is something you create yourself. To make it in Android Studio, right click the `drawable` folder and choose **New > Image Asset**. For the **Icon Type** choose **Notification Icons**.

[image]