# Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification

when app going to the background
and send notification from firebase
my log print

[image]

but when the app at the foreground
I can receive notification and can read data from ExtraPayLoad
but at background cant receive data

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483563/6834114

Comment: i fix icon problem but I still cant read data from extrapayload and make notification actions