# How Should I Change My Pushnotification Icon For My app

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to change my push notification icon.

**Code Snippet :**

```
public class Mymessagingservice extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public  void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    getimage(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

}
public void getimage(String title,String message){

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"mynotification")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.otplogo
            ))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.otplogo)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(message);


    NotificationManagerCompat manager =NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    manager.notify(999,builder.build());

}
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem? Does the code work?

Comment: code is working ...i want to set my icon for notification when app is in background

Comment: in foreground my icon is visible ...but in background black circle is coming

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:icon="@drawable/otplogo"

        />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_colour"
            android:resource="@color/white" />

Comment: i had used this also in manifest

Comment: then why didn't you mention that in question?

Comment: while writing in question your editor was showing error

Comment: please tell me the solution

Comment: `your editor ` I don't have any editor. `please tell me the solution` please don;t ask people to tell you the solution. It is already obvious that you want them to do that.

Comment: `black circle is coming` is that black circle your app's icon?

Comment: yaa thats my app icon

Comment: how should i set an image to that icon

Comment: And you want another icon, right? It shows default icon if not set to another. Check the documentation on how to set another icon in background: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidNotification Also you can check this github issue as an example: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/121#issuecomment-403492027

Comment: is that compulsory to add json file to app like showing in link

Comment: that is not a json file to add to the app, that is the json which you send the notification with to firebase API. How do you send pushes?

Comment: i am sebding pushes through firebase cloud

Comment: Is that some web UI for pushes, or you are calling the API?

Comment: Please include images in the questions... and also your questions in detail

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this was a limitation of Firebase Notifications in SDK 9.0.0-9.6.1. When the app is in the background the launcher icon is use from the manifest (with the requisite Android tinting) for messages sent from the console.

With SDK 9.8.0 however, you can override the default! In your AndroidManifest.xml you can set the following fields to customise the icon and color:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/google_blue" />
```

Note that if the app is in the foreground (or a data message is sent) you can completely use your own logic to customise the display. You can also always customise the icon if sending the message from the HTTP/XMPP APIs.

You have to put this tag inside Application tag of manifest

Official doc- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Thanks to this guy - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37332514/4741746

Answer (score 0):

Bro its too simple but you have to do it carefully.

First, make a black & white icon for your notification.
Now set it in your `notification` as a `small icon` like below.

```
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_icon);
```

now you can set a color but if I am right so you can set only predefined color instead of custom. For custom color you can try with your logic I am giving you a code of a predefined color.

```
 mBuilder.setColor(Color.GREEN);
```

It will make your `notification icon` Color green.
Happy Coding!!!

**UPDATE**
Code for custom notification.

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
            0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getApplicationContext()
            .getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sniper_gun);


    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_icon);
    mBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
    if (image!=null) {
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setLargeIcon(image)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image).setSummaryText(message).bigLargeIcon(null))
                .setColor(Color.GREEN)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    }
//        else {
//            mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
//                    .setContentText(message)
//                    .setAutoCancel(false)
//                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
//                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
//        }

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

        // set custom soundUri
        if(soundUri != null){
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .build();
            notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes);
        }

        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mNotificationManager.notify(0 /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: sir i am using apk level 29..here channel is goig to be used

Comment: what's the problem bro can use it in your code as  `.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_icon);` and  `.setColor(Color.GREEN);`.

Comment: @Egaragee I am also using API level 29.

Comment: i want this icon when my app is in background...and that it takes icon from manifest

Comment: in manifest new concept of channel is there <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
like that

Comment: so how should i set icon default_notification_channel_id

Comment: @Egaragee Do you want a whole code of notification. and It also takes a notification icon from your code.

Comment: yaa whole code i want if possible..bcoz its not there anywhere on internet

Comment: I shared it, bro.

Comment: if it is useful for you so please accept as an answer